# Wordpress: How to keep reply/comment box open by default

Tags: wordpress, comments

I would like the reply textarea to be visible all the time, not just when the user clicks the comments link (generated by comments_popup_link).

I have googled this and drawn a blank - 1 post advised using comments_template() instead of comments_popup_link but that doesn't work. It seems like it should be straightforward but I can't figure it out - can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using comment_form(); instead of comments_popup_link();.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

Comment: Thanks - sorry but I should have mentioned that I'd also like the comments to appear too - but thanks again that did bring up the comments box at least. Any ideas?

Comment: wp_list_comments(); -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments 

Your friends are the "related function" references at the bottom of WP Codex pages. :)

Comment: OK - I got the answer - the comments_template worked when you put withcomments before:

$withcomments = true; 
comments_template();

Comment: Mind accepting my answer then if you've gotten it working? :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks aendrew for your help - finally the code I used to get my comments functionality working was:

$withcomments = true; 
comments_template();